# Issue in using a LIST in Tcl

Tags: list, tcl

I have defined a variable in the following format.

```
set ast_protocol_FilePath {
  abcdefghijk.spf
}
```

And my code calls this variable in the following fashion.

```
if { [info exists ast_protocol_FilePath] && ( [llength $ast_protocol_FilePath]) }  { 
    run_drc $ast_protocol_FilePath
}
```

However, I see an error because of the way list is defined. $ast_protocol_FilePath is

```
Error: Unable to open read file "
    abcdefghijk.spf
"
```

ideally the $ast_protocol_FilePath should have been defined as " abcdefghijk.spf " and not in the new line format.

Is there a way out here? I don't want to define list as

```
set ast_protocol_FilePath { abcdefghijk.spf }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `string trim` to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
run_drc [string trim $ast_protocol_FilePath]
```

or if you want to continue to treat the variable as a list, `lindex`:

```
run_drc [lindex $ast_protocol_FilePath 0]
```

Comment: Is there a way I write in bashrc, tclshrc or somewhere that string trim is ran by default on each variable?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [Shawn's suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71386905/301832), you can also do this:

```
run_drc {*}$ast_protocol_FilePath
```

That (expansion syntax) takes the words in the list and uses them each as a separate argument. When there's just one word and some extra spaces and newlines, as in your case, it gets rid of that pesky whitespace.